# Running a .bat windows batch file from excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, prompt

I have a file called `newcurl.bat` sitting inside the current directory that my excel file is in

I want excelVBA to run this file

I tried:

`Shell "cmd.exe /k ""cd " & """ & ThisWorkbook.path & """ & " newcurl.bat"""`

but it only CD's to the current folder path but does not physically run the `newcurl.bat` file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out.

I had a personal.xlsb macrobook so `thisworkbook.path` was referencing the wrong workbook.

I ended up doing this instead:

```
Dim folderPath As String
Dim shellCommand As String

folderPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path
shellCommand = """" & folderPath & "\" & "newcurl.bat" & """"
Call Shell(shellCommand, vbNormalFocus)
```

Answer (score 0):

You messed up the double quotes - `ThisWorkbook.path` is literally used in the command.

You can see for yourself, if you print the command to the console:

```
Dim strCommand As String
strCommand = "cmd.exe /k ""cd " & """ & ThisWorkbook.path & """ & " newcurl.bat"""
Debug.Print strCommand
Shell strCommand
```

Comment: i ended up doing something different in the comment above which worked for me.